# Does PHP have anything like Ruby's irb?

Tags: php

If I want to try out something new in Ruby or Javascript, I love getting immediate feedback from `irb` or the JS console in Firebug.

Is there anything like that for PHP?

### Update

As @bernie pointed out, such tools are called REPLs - "Read-eval-print loop"

Comment: REPL:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Run `php -a` in the command-line. But this does not work on Windows.

For Windows, you may want to try [phpa-norl](http://www.fischerlaender.net/php/phpa-norl).

Comment: Haven't tried php-norl yet, but "does not work on Windows" was useful info for me. To expound on that: it starts up and acts like it's working on Windows, but you can't really do anything (like echo a variable). It does work on Linux, though. It's not as great as irb, but... :) It's helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that both "php -a" option & php-norl, have one limitation, if your PHP code throws major exception/error, it will crash the shell and you have to start up shell again. The plus side though is the terminal/shell will have remembered your previous lines so you can up/down to re-execute w/o retyping. But this crash limitation makes PHP shell nowhere as powerful as the shells of Ruby (I assume, haven't tried Ruby), Python, and Java (via Beanshell) where the shell catches your exceptions and you can still continue from same shell session, your bad code just didn't execute.

Comment: Ruby is by all means awesome... but for basic operations with PHP this is great and thanks for that..  PHP or for that matter coding in Windows, I would say is a disappointment...

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is a way: php -a, 
-a means interactive shell

Comment: I have installed lampp on ubuntu 10.04. How can I get php -a command working ?

Answer (score 3):

php -a is the closest thing I know of but it's not quite like irb. irb will execute each line at a time. php -a will wait until you press ctrl-D (for end of line) and will then execute all lines.

Answer (score 3):

How about phpsh?  It's not fully compatible with PHP, but it represents a serious effort.

http://www.phpsh.org

Answer (score 3):

## Boris

I'm not working with PHP currently, but I just spotted this online and remembered I had once asked this question. Boris looks very nice.

https://github.com/d11wtq/boris

Comment: installed with brew. Looks very nice and more user friendly than `php -a`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Mac, I find the PHP Code Tester program a much better way to accomplish the same thing: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/37328/php-code-tester